# One year of Ubuntu experience, still not an expert?

Tags: 10.04

Google always helps to find solution, but most of the time i just copy paste all the codes that are suggested. Sometimes it works like charm, sometimes i screw up my Ubuntu. Not anymore. I really want to know whats under the hood and how these things work. So, please suggest me how to get started from the very basic of Ubuntu, perhaps more generally linux.

Answer (score 4):

Install VirtualBox, set up an Ubuntu guest inside it, checkpoint it, and start experimenting.  Restore from the checkpoint if you mess things up too much — after exploring to see *why* it broke.  Best way I know of to learn.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned the problem.You just copy and paste the commands.You search and find your answers so the command you're finding are needed.Search for them and learn about them.

An alternative solution is `man`.For sure you know about it.`man command` will give you valuable information.

[image]

[linuxmanpages.com](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/) is great too.You can view linux manuals online in categories

---

For more information you can find great free books in http://www.tldp.org/guides.html

**The Linux System Administrator's Guide** among them is fantastic and gives you a good view of linux and it's structure.Don't  miss it.

You can download the PDF version [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/sag.pdf) and read it online [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/index.html).

---

Of course there are many solutions to learn linux but learning the needed commands and searching about my linux questions was the most efficient way for me.

**EDIT:**

There are many books from famous publishers about linux but there is no need to pay money.Fortunately we're using free softwares world products and we have many free resources to learn.